# Viewing Delayed::Job queue in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, delayed-job

In my Rails app, I have a delayed job which is executed a period of time after the record is saved:

`after_save { self.delay.method }`

For my Rspec test I want to test that the job is indeed in the queue (by using `Delayed::Job.count`). If I call that inside the `after_save` callback, the count does go up by 1, and using `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false` I can verify that it will run. However, inside Rspec, it still sees the count as 0 (I assume this is because it was executed in another thread). Any ideas?